# Mixing Out and Named Parameters in C#: Why Does Out Parameter Need to be Named As Well?

Tags: c#, named-parameters, out-parameters, compiler-bug

**Short Version**: A named argument following an `out` argument gives a compiler error, but I cannot find any support for this behaviour in the language specification.

**Long Version**:

I'm using the `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>` three parameter overload, but I would prefer to name the `ignoreCase` parameter to make my code clearer, a call like:

```
MyEnum res;
b = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(inputString, true, out res);
```

leaves the meaning of the boolean unclear (unless this method is known<sup>1</sup>). Hence I would like to use:

```
b = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(inputString, out res, ignoreCase: true);
```

However the compiler reports this as an error:

> Named argument 'ignoreCase' specifies a parameter for which a positional argument has already been given

and the IDE highlights the `ignoreCase` parameter. VS2010 targeting .NET 4, and VS11 Beta targeting either 4 or 4.5 all give the same result. In all cases naming the `out` parameter removes the error.

```
b = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(inputString, result: out res, ignoreCase: true);
```

I've tried this across a number of different methods (including avoiding generics)<sup>2</sup>, both from the framework and in my assembly: always the same result: an `out` parameter followed by a named parameter gives an error.

I can see no reason for this error, and §7.5.1 *Argument Lists* of the *C# Language Specification: Version 4.0* does not seem to provide any reason why an `out` followed by a named parameter should give an error. The text of the error seems to support an interpretation as a bug: there is no positional argument which could be a valid match for `ignoreCase`.

Is my reading of the specification wrong? Or is this a compiler bug?

***C# 7.2 Update***

This restriction on all named arguments have to follow positional arguments when calling was lifted with C# 7.2.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2#non-trailing-named-arguments.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hence the advice in the Framework Design Guidelines to prefer `enum` parameters.

<sup>2</sup> Eg: given:

```
private static void TestMethod(int one, float two, out string three) {
  three = "3333";
}
```

this this call also gives the same error on the named parameter unless the `out` parameter is also named:

```
TestMethod(1, out aString, two: 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Named parameters do not allow you to "skip" positional arguments.

Your code is parsed as passing the first two arguments—`value` and `ignoreCase`, then passing `ignoreCase` again.
It has nothing to do with the `out`ness of the parameter.

You can fix it by passing the last parameter as named too.

Comment: On re-reading the spec, I can see this approach. Shame it doesn't use the PowerShell approach: match named parameters with named arguments and then remaining positional parameters with remaining positional arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Every positional argument needs to match, if you start rearranging the order by naming the arguments, you must rearrange all the arguments following the one you named.

So this line of code:

```
b = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(inputString, out res, ignoreCase: true);
```

Tries to match `out res` with `ignoreCase`, and then you come along naming that parameter again, which trips the compiler up. Likely there is another error just lurking behind the first one, that `out res` is not a match for `ignoreCase`.

So if you want to "skip" ignoreCase when dealing with positional arguments, you must name the `out res` argument as well.